# How to use inputSlider with top_n in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I want to use numeric input from a slider to change available size of options in my app. I have all my code running, except the selection for the top_n subgroups is not working. I am getting the Error:

> Error in : `n` must be a scalar integer

I tried to convert input$selected_precision to various datatype but to no success. I also tried dplyr::slice, but that also didn't work because it returned unexpected results.

So my questions is: How can turn my input$selected_precision into a scalar integer?

Here is my code (the code which raises the error is in line 58):

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(shinyWidgets)
groupA <- sort(rep(c('AA'),16))
groupB <- sort(rep(c('BB'),32))
group <- c(groupA, groupB)
subgroupA <- rep(c('AAA','BBB'),8)
subgroupB <- rep(c('EEE','FFF','GGG','HHH'),8)
subgroup <- c(subgroupA, subgroupB)
one <- rep(1990,4)
two <- rep(1991,4)
three <- rep(1992,4)
four <- rep(1993,4)
year <- as.character(rep(c(one,two,three,four),3))
relValue <- rnorm(48, 30, 10)
df <- data.frame(group, subgroup, year, relValue, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput(inputId = 'selected_group', label = 'group', choices = ''),

    uiOutput("selected_precision"),

    pickerInput(inputId = 'selected_subgroup', label = 'subgroup', choices = '', multiple = TRUE),

    verbatimTextOutput('text', placeholder = TRUE))
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session,
                      'selected_group',
                      choices = unique(df$group))})

  maxNum <- reactive({
    df %>%
      filter(group == input$selected_group) %>%
      distinct(subgroup) %>%
      summarise(n = n()) %>%
      .$n})

  output$selected_precision <- renderUI({

    sliderInput('selected_precision', label = 'precision', min = 1, max = maxNum(),
                value = maxNum(), round = TRUE, step = 1)})

  filteredChoices <- eventReactive({
    maxNum()
    input$selected_group}, {

      df %>%
        filter(group == input$selected_group) %>%
        group_by(subgroup) %>%
        summarise(avg = mean(relValue)) %>%
        arrange(desc(avg)) %>%
        top_n(input$selected_precision, avg) %>% ### If you change the input$ to any integer the code will run
        .[[1]]})

  observeEvent({
    filteredChoices
    input$selected_group}, {

      updatePickerInput(
        session,
        'selected_subgroup',
        choices = filteredChoices(),
        selected = filteredChoices()
      )})

  output$text <- renderText({input$selected_precision})

}
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 1):

The first time the `filderedChoices` block runs, `input$selected_precision` will be `NULL` because the input hasn't yet updated after the corresponding UI component was rendered.

You need to handle the `NULL`, e.g.:

```
n <- input$selected_precision
if (is.null(n)) {
    n <- maxNum()
}
```

And then use `top_n(n, avg)` later.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the NULL direction! I used a different approach however, putting the input$selected_precision into the input variables section of the filteredChoices block.